# Firebase new Cloud Function throws INTERNAL error

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform

Im working on a project in Vue.js 3 Typescript and Firebase.
When trying to implement new cloud functions i suddenly encountered the following problem:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: FirebaseError: INTERNAL

My old Cloud Functions work just as expected, but trying to add one that deletes a document it suddenly occurred. I tried breaking it down thinking it was probably a syntactical problem, but even copying the whole boilerplate from another working cloud function did not help.
Next i started to strip the function of its guts.
Two things i discovered:

**1. Barebones**

```
exports.deleteSingleCourse = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall(async (data: any, context: any) => {

  console.log('teachersRef')
  return "teachersRef"
})
```

> Output: {data: 'teachersRef'}

This code works as expected so there is no mistake when calling the function.

**2. Just a little more**

```
exports.deleteSingleCourse = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall(async (data: any, context: any) => {

  const teachersRef = db.collection(db, 'schools/' + 'y70B7KSbwd2D55SRPItY' + "/teachers");
  console.log(teachersRef)

  return "test"
})
```

> Output: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: FirebaseError: INTERNAL

This code somehow already stops working entirely and throws the before mentioned error.
Note: The console.log is only there to have used "teachersRef" variable in order to stop Firebase from cancelling the function deployment.

Just before this problem i accidentally had two different cloud functions in my index.ts with the same name and deployed them. I changed the names upon noticing, removed them from within the firebase console and re-deployed. I don't know if this could have anything to do with my problem but just wanted to mention it in case.

Comment: Which version of the Admin SDK are you using? And how do you import the Admin SDK module?

Comment: I import it into the index.ts like this: const admin = require('firebase-admin'). The Version i get using npm firebase-admin -v is 8.11.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Admin SDK version 8 you cannot use the modular syntax and you need to use the global `admin` namespace.

Therefore
`const teachersRef = db.collection(db, 'schools/' + 'y70B7KSbwd2D55SRPItY' + "/teachers");`

must be changed to

`const teachersRef = admin.firestore().collection('schools/' + 'y70B7KSbwd2D55SRPItY' + "/teachers");`

---

If you want to use the modular syntax, you'll need to upgrade your Admin SDK version to version 10 and change the way you import it, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-node-v10#typescript) in the doc.

Comment: Perfect it works. But why does the other approach work in my other cloud functions?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "the other approach"? Other Cloud Functions? Without their code I cannot answer.

Comment: I have another function for example that first creates a user, .then() sets some custom claims and uses this exact line of code:     let schoolRef = db.collection('schools').doc(data.schoolID).collection('teachers').doc(userRecord.uid). Which is the same modular syntax i can not use in the new cloud function which this question is about

Comment: `db.collection('schools').doc(data.schoolID).collection('teachers').doc(userRecord.uid)` is not the modular syntax so it is normal this line works with the Admin SDK v8. (`db` should be equal to `admin.firestioe()`)